# Limits of integration for expectation of absolute value of difference between two exponential variables.

Tags: probability, absolute-value, exponential-distribution

Let $X,Y$ iid and $\sim Exp(\lambda)$.

Find $E[|X-Y|]$

Would someone tell me what the limits of integration are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: use symmetry.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\lvert X-Y\rvert) &= \mathsf E((X-Y)\mathbf 1_{Y<X})+\mathsf E((Y-X)\mathbf 1_{X\leqslant Y})
\\[2ex] &= 2~\mathsf E((X-Y)\mathbf 1_{Y<X})
\\[2ex] &{= 2~\iint_{y<x} (x-y)\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)~\mathrm d (x,y)}
\end{align}$$

Comment: So, the limits of integration for $y$ are $[0,x]$ and the limits for $x$ are from $0$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @Numbers I assume you meant to have an equality sign where you have your inequality sign in that expression? If so, it's elementary - if $E_n$ is a sequence of disjoint events such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n = \Omega$ then $\mathbb E[Z] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb E[Z\mathsf 1_{E_n}]$. Here $\Omega = \{Y<X\}\cup\{X\leqslant Y\}$ so we take the sum of the expectations on those events to compute the expectation of $|X-Y|$.

Comment: I have doubts about this answer. I am finding that
$$
2\int_0^x (x-y) f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathsf dy = x^2,
$$
and clearly
$$
\int_0^\infty x^2\ \mathsf dx = +\infty.
$$
But by the triangle inequality,
$$
\mathbb E[|X-Y|] \leqslant \mathbb E[|X|] + \mathbb E[|Y|] = \frac2\lambda,
$$
so $|X-Y|$ should be integrable.

Comment: Interchanging the order of the iterated integrals, we too have
$$
\int_0^\infty (x-y)\ \mathsf dy = +\infty,
$$
so indeed I believe your expression gives an infinite value whereas the mean is actually finite.

Comment: @Math1000 So are you saying the accepted answer is wrong?

Comment: @Numbers This is a perfectly fine general answer. Did you actually try finding the integral?

Comment: @Math1000 $2\int_0^x (x-y) f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathsf dy = x^2$ cannot be true.

Comment: My bad, I was integrating the wrong function. Indeed,
$$
2 \int_0^x (x-y) \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda  x} e^{-\lambda  y} \, dy = 2 e^{-2 \lambda  x} \left(e^{\lambda  x} (\lambda  x-1)+1\right).
$$

Comment: Is the actual answer negative one over lambda?

Comment: No. The expectation of an absolute-valued function will be non-negative.$$2 \int_0^\infty \lambda x \mathrm e^{-\lambda x}-\mathrm e^{-\lambda x}+\mathrm e^{-2\lambda x}\mathrm d x = \lambda^{-1}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp In Wolfram Mathematica, I tried Integrate[
 2*(x - y)*Exp[-p*x]*Exp[-p*y]*p^2, {y, 0, Infinity}, {x, 0, y}]. This yields $\frac{-1}{\lambda}$ assuming $x \leq y$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp If I tried 'Integrate[
 2*(x - y)*Exp[-p*x]*Exp[-p*y]*p^2, {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, x}], then I obtain that the integral converges to $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. This is for the case that $y<x$. You are right that the expectation is symmetric but I think we had to consider absolute values of the expectations. Would you please edit your answer to reflect this phenomenon?

Comment: Yes, @Numbers , but `int[ p^2 (y-x) exp(-p x) exp(-p y), {y, 0, infty}, {x,0,y}]= 1/(2p)`   Remember when $0<x<y$, there $\lvert x-y\rvert=y-x$ .  That is why the two parts are equal, by reason of their symmetry.